# updating treeview without postback

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have updatepanel inside it I have tabcontainer and inside it I have panel but again inside the panel I have treeview I don't want to change the order.
let back to inside of the updatepanel I have button to add some treeview nodes programmitically and it works but I can refresh treeview or databind actually there is no data I just add some directory info to treeview and whenever I change them it is not updated until I do postback by the browser-refresh-button, I don't know why? what am I doing now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treeview inside updatepanel is not supported officially. However you can work around almost all of the difficulties, and its almost. At times, it will still do a full postback. You can read http://www.geekays.net/post/Using-TreeView-inside-AJAX-UpdatePanel.aspx to see the details.

Let me know if you have some specific issues. Your question is not very clear.

**Edit note:**

You can look at [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) for an alternate. It seems it is very good, though I have not used it.

Comment: I dont have only treeview in my updatepanel I have a lots of control ajax and other user control is it work properly?

Comment: is there any other componant compatible with updatepanel that work similar can I use other componant instead it ? I just want to show folder and files those are existed in host there is icon and text click event handler for treeview

Comment: @kamiar3001: I have edited my response. See the edit note. Also see why a postback is not happening on the click of the button. Or is it happening, but the tree is not getting updated? You may edit your post for clarity. Also I said, the treeview is not compatible, other controls will be working as long as they are compatible. Read the details in the link I provided.